# References memory at 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

Tags: x86-64

So I'm learning x86 and to do that I've chosen to do so alongside understanding how to hook functions. I already have a pretty good understanding of C++ so thats the language I've chosen to do it in. At the moment I have a jump which jumps to my trampoline but its currently erroring saying the code references memory at 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF but I can't see where that is

This is the code that its saying its erroring at (Using IDA as my disassembler/debugger)

```
FF 25 8A B9 FD FF       jmp     qword ptr cs:unk_7FF8C3700000
```

This jump is based on a displacement of 0xfffdb98a (-149110)

The code at 07FF8C3700000

```
48 B8 90 10 20 B8 F8 7F mov     rax, 7FF8B8201090h
FF E0                   jmp     rax
48 89 5C 24 10          mov     [rsp+10h], rbx
48 89 74 24 20          mov     [rsp+20h], rsi
FF 25 74 46 02 00       jmp     qword ptr cs:loc_7FF8C372468A+6
```

The first jump is too my hooked function, The two `mov` are the damaged instructions from overriting with my jmp hook and the last jump is back to the original function just past my added jump/hook. However going off IDA it isnt even reaching my trampoline its just not able to execute my jump to my trampoline

Comment: Probably it means that after `jmp     qword ptr cs:unk_7FF8C3700000` loads 8 bytes from memory into RIP, code-fetch from the new RIP fails.  e.g. because the pointer in memory was `-1`.  `FF 25` ... is memory-indirect jump with a RIP-relative addressing mode, not a relative jump to that code at `07FF8C3700000` you disassembled.  In fact it's using those code bytes *as* an address.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ah thank you so the jmp just needs to be an E9 instead of an FF. That'll be a good lesson to not use an online assembler to write my bytecode for me, I'll do it myself in the future. If you want to add your comment as an answer I'll be sure to mark it as an answer. Thanks!